# Why is Sitecore hijacking my 404 item to the ItemNotFoundUrl?

Tags: http-status-code-404, sitecore, sitecore6

I want to use a Sitecore item as a 404 page, in order to have translated 404s and separate 404 pages for different sites.  I have created a sublayout called Render404, in which the only code is to set the HTTP status code on the response, like so:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Response.StatusCode = 404;  //gotta set our HTTP response code, otherwise this rendering does nothing
    }
```

I created a test 404 page and dropped in this rendering.  Loaded up the page in my browser.  Works great, get the expected 404 code.

Then I pushed it up to the live site.  Fails miserably.  Sitecore continuously gives me the default ItemNotFoundUrl page when I try to access my test 404 directly.  The really odd thing is that it works fine in preview, which makes me think it's a publishing issue.  But **IT IS NOT**.  The items are showing up fine in the Web DB.  Further, if I remove the 404 control, the page renders OK and there is no redirection.  Sitecore is somewhere seeing the 404 status and doing a redirect.  Even though there is a context item.  And this behavior does not occur in my dev system.

Suggestions?

Further info:
I've tried it with ServerSideRedirect true/false.  Doesn't change anything.

Comment: It could be configuration differences between your Preview/Live instances.  If you use the /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx tool in "live" does it show the expected configuration value for ItemNotFoundUrl? What about other related configuration?

Comment: ItemNotFoundUrl is set correctly.  However, would this matter?  I'm specifically requesting an existing Sitecore item... that happens to be returning a 404 status code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try please with :

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
Response.StatusCode = 404;
Response.StatusDescription = "Page not found";
Response.Flush();
```

The `TrySkipIisCustomErrors` property is used only when your application is hosted in IIS 7.0. When running in Classic mode in IIS 7.0 the `TrySkipIisCustomErrors` property default value is `true`. When running in Integrated mode, the `TrySkipIisCustomErrors` property default value is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors` as mentioned in the other response. But anyway, I would suggest you using the [Sitecore Error Manager](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_Error_Manager.aspx) shared source module from the Marketplace. It does exactly what you would like to to. If you don't want to add the module, you can have a look at the source code at [Github](https://github.com/unic/SitecoreErrorManager) how we solved the problem there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  We originally thought this was going to be a very easy fish to fry... just a few lines of code.  We like to avoid 3rd party solutions if rolling our own is quick and easy.  This one just got away from me.

Comment: I'm using on current project Sitecore Error Manager and I recommend to use it,it really easy to configure.